# Do Guardians get to choose their class when they're resurrected?

Tags: destiny-2

We know that Ghosts, using a fraction of the Travellers light, resurrect souls to become Guardians, but are people resurrected as a Warlock for example?

Or is it simply that people are resurrected and choose a role when they become a Guardian?

Is this covered in the lore at any point?

Comment: [This](https://www.bungie.net/ar/Forums/Post/243965300) Bungie forum discussion has a great explanation, but it's not sourced. So not really sure how accurate or canonical it is

Comment: i found this passage from quora
In game, yes. It’s be rather lame if your choice was randomly assigned.

However. From a lore standpoint, it is randomly assigned. If the light thinks that you should be a Titan, then you get resurrected as a Titan when your Ghost first finds and revives you. If it thinks your more compatible as a Warlock or Hunter, then that’s what you get revived as. I mean, before you get resurrected the first time, your dead. Dead dead. How can you make the choice as to your class when your dead? The Traveler and his Ghost’s light does it for you.
should i post as answer

Comment: Having sourced two opposing views on this, we can say that neither are canonical. Perhaps it is not explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the classes aren't that much defined lore-wise. Any guardian can learn any ability, just like we can learn a new sport. Basically, any guardian can do whatever they want with the light, taking into consideration they have the knowledge and dedication to learn the skill. Quoting the Reddit user u/cptenn94:

> It is important to note that the traveler didn't create ghosts to "go
> forth and bring me hunters Titans and warlocks". It created ghosts to
> revive the chosen to rise up to defend it and humanity.
>
> All classes and abilities are just made up by the risen/guardians on
> their own.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyLore/comments/cmgw3n/do_guardians_get_to_choose_their_class_andor_can/